# Как прочитать содержимое файла в GWT?

Tags: gwt, java

Как прочитать содержимое текстового файла из клиента (GWT)? Файл лежит на сервере в папке с ресурсами (картинками).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В GWT можно использовать как ресурсы картинки, текстовые, бинарные и css файлы. Вот пример:

```
public interface MyBundle extends ClientBundle {
  public static final MyBundle Instance = GWT.create(MyBundle.class);

  @Source("textFile.txt") 
  public TextResource text();
}
```

Полное описание [здесь](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#I18N).

Answer (score 0):

У вас два варианта:

1. Запросить через GWT-RPC нужные данные, а сервер пусть прочтёт файлы, пропарсит и вернёт данные, содержащиеся в файлах в нормальном виде
2. Если нужно получить обязательно именно сам текст из файла, то можно использовать [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html), сделать GET-запрос с его помощью и получить файлы.

Comment: То есть через GWT.create(...) это нельзя сделать никаким образом?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду compile-time?

Comment: Да. Если это возможно)

Comment: Да, это точно возможно. Я знаю точно, что таким способом создаются GWT-шные таймзоны, но работают только те, на которые есть явные ссылки (какая-то мудрёная оптимизация GWT-компилятора). Сейчас не помню, за счёт чего это работает.. завтра гляну.